# MYSQL JSON extract IN vs OR

Tags: mysql

I am running two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.source') IN ('A', 'B');
SELECT * FROM t WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.source') = 'A' OR JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.source') = 'B';
```

The first query returns `0` rows, and the second query returns `1000` rows.

Why is there a difference?

I am running MYSQL 5.7

Comment: theoretically they should both work identically. basic debugging time: select out the json_extract() call itself, e.g. `select json_extrac(...)` and do some poking around on the returned value. check string lengths. check for padding, etc...

Comment: What is the content of your JSON `data`?

Comment: For the purpose of this question, it is just a flat object with several string fields, one of which is `source`.

Comment: @MarcB If I do `SELECT DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.source') FROM t;` then I get both `A` and `B` as returned values

Comment: and what's `length()` of those values return? it  SHOULD be just `1`.

Comment: No, the length comes back as 3... okay so it works if i `JSON_UNQUOTE`. Why is the behavior not the same for `IN ('A') ` and `IN ('A', 'B')` respectively

Comment: Sounds like a mysql bug. Since this is a relatively new feature, there are likely to be some.

Comment: You can use the `data->>'$.source'` to extract and unquote in one step.